# Splitting a string with a double delimiter

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to understand how to split a string in lua with this format

```
hello - mynameis - jeff
```

I simply want to get the name "jeff". The delimiter will be an `-` and a  .
This is what I actually tried:

```
local result = string.gmatch(line, "[-\s]+")
```

Which doesn't work. How would I do it?

Comment: "*The delimiter will be an `-` and a .*" Wouldn't the delimiter be " - "? That is, a dash surrounded by spaces?

Comment: Checkout my https://github.com/moteus/lua-split library. `result = split(line, ' - ', true)` or `result = split(line, '%s*%-%s*')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of a workarounds can be replacing all " - " with a character that is not used in the content you have, and then get the last part with a simple negated character class with a `$` end-of-string anchor:

```
local example = "hello - mynameis - jeff"
example = string.gsub(example, " %- ", "\x02")
local result = string.match(example, "[^\x02]+$")
print(result)
```

See the [Lua IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/hmOgm6)

With `" %- "`, all *`space` + `-` + `space`* substrings are replace with the temporary character, and then only the substring after the last temporary character is matched with `[^\x02]+$` pattern.

I used the `STX` control character (`\x02`), but you may choose another that you are sure will be missing in the contents to parse.